# How do I download an Xcode project From SVN?

Tags: xcode, svn

I have been given SVN access to a repository which is in the form of `svn://xxx/repo-name/trunk`

How do I download the source code onto my local hard drive?

I have tried using the terminal on Mac with the following command:

`#svn checkout svn://xxx:portnumber/repo-name/trunk`

This does not seem to have helped.

I have also tried to use the Organizer in Xcode to setup the repository with no luck.

Also: if the project gets downloaded, is it saved in the root directory on my hard drive?

Comment: `svn checkout svn://xxx:portnumber/repo-name/trunk`
normally will save the repository to a directory called 'trunk'. what's the output of this command?

Comment: i get the error invalid hostname i was wondering if should remove the svn:// from the url and replace with it http or run the command without either of the two